# cake php AppController and inheritance

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

In many tutorial of Acl component in cakephp
i got instruction that add component either in AppController or in all the other controllers which inherits AppController.......

but problem  is

```
var $components=array('Auth',Acl);
```

when i use the above line in AppConroller i cant use the Auth or Acl component...
but when i use the same code in all the child classes it works fine........

what will be the problem

here is my appController

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {

     var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session','CssMenu');
     var $components = array('Auth');

     function beforeFilter() {
        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';
        $this->Auth->authError = "Sorry, you are lacking access.";
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Login';
}

}
?>
```

code for usersController

```
<?php
class userssController extends AppController{
    var $name="Logins";
    //var $components = array('Auth');
    var $layout='login';

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' => 'index');
    }
}
?>
```

when i comment the line 4 this will b error
on uncomment it works fine
thanks in advance

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Cake are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be something wrong in your code.If you add the line in `/app/cake/libs/controller/app_controller.php`,every child class should be able to use the components.See [about app_controller in cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/829/The-App-Controller):

CakePHP merges the following variables from the AppController to your application's controllers:`$components,$helpers,$uses`

EDit @deceze

you may write your own customized base controller in `/app/yourown_app_controller.php`

```
class YourOwnAppController extends Controller
{
       var $components = array("Auth");
}
```

then use it by a requirment like `require_once(APP."yourown_app_controller.php");` in the child contrller file.

Comment: +1 for the general consensus that it should be available if put into AppController, -1 for suggesting to edit `/cake/libs/*`. Never touch the `/cake` directory unless there's a bug to fix. You can and should put the `app_controller.php` in your `/app` directory!

Comment: Sorry, your edit is wrong as well. You make a class called `AppController` in a file called `app_controller.php` in your `/app` directory. That's the way it's supposed to be done, Cake explicitly supports it this way. http://book.cakephp.org/view/829/The-App-Controller

Comment: @deceze,I'm afraid I cannot agree with you at this point.It's not necessary to make custom `appcontroller` always as `app_controller.php`,because people may not always need only one kind of base controller to extend.

Comment: Okay, technically, you *can* make custom base controllers, true. It's bad to forgo convention though, especially with no gain. If you have a situation where you need two different base controllers (...?) you could use this method, but that has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @deceze,In my last project for recruiting ,we used some base controllers for different roles such as jobseeker,admin,companyusers..etc,I think it's better than just extend one `appcontroller`.:)

Comment: thanks guys thanks for this informative discussion.Now i understood were i am going wrong and corrected.

Comment: @SpawnCxy : can i have a base controller which extends AppController for UsersController???if possible where i need to place the base controller (i mean which directory)-----------------
so my hierarchy will be AppController->BaseController->UsersController

Comment: @RSK,yes,that's possible.Place the base controller in `app/` and require it as my answer said.

Comment: how can i use myown login function to authenticate users in cakePHP
because my users table structure is different from the cakePHP structure.

even i overridden the login function it still executing the login function in parent class

Answer (score 5):

I managed to pull this off. I had a pair of controllers that shared some methods, but other controllers in the application did not (and could not) use those methods because certain data had to be present in the model. Moreover, the controller containing the shared methods should not be allowed to be called in the URL, which was an extra challenge.

1. Create a controller in your controllers folder called shared_controller.php. Define some shared methods in it, and make sure it extends AppController:

   ```
   class SharedController extends AppController {
   ```
2. My subcontrollers were extending AppController. Change this to extend SharedController instead. I couldn't get the shared controller to autoload, so I added an App::import above that:

   ```
   App::import('Controller', 'Shared');
   class SubController extends SharedController {
   ```
3. Components and helpers must be merged into their parent variables manually; otherwise the child classes will overwrite them. Define a __construct method in each subcontroller and call array_merge on the components, helpers, and whatever else. Call the parent constructor at the end. Note: this cannot be done in beforeFilter

   ```
   function __construct(){
       $this->components = array_merge($this->components,array('Mycomponent'));
       parent::__construct();
   }
   ```
4. If you call http://example.com/shared/method, you'll probably get an error that you're missing a database table, or missing a view. I didn't need any methods from Shared to be called directly, so I defined a route to just redirect to the homepage:

   ```
   Router::connect('/shared/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
   ```

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is wondering why their `$components` and `$helpers` overwrite instead of merging after changing inheritance is because you need to define `protected $_mergeParent = 'YourParentClass';`.  By default this is set to 'AppController'.

Source: [CakePHP 2.4 Source Code](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#294-301)